# How to redirect localhost:9292/json to localhost:80/ using Nginx reverse proxy?

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

```
 server {   
        listen 80;
        server_name localhost;
        location / {
            index index.html;
            root /Users/Lin/Codes/JS/Emberjs/yeoman-ember/dist;
        }  

        location ~* ^/json {
            root
            proxy_pass http://localhost:9292;

        }
    }
```

The configure kinda works, but it only pass

`localhost:9292/json` to `localhost/json`.

But What I want is

`localhost:9292/json` to 'localhost'

`localhost:9292/json/post` to 'localhost/post'

I think what I need to do is set root or do some rewrite, Anyone has some idea?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass all connections from port 9092 to 80 you are listening the wrong port.

Change the port you are listening to 9092:

```
server {   
    listen 9092;
    server_name localhost;

    root /Users/Lin/Codes/JS/Emberjs/yeoman-ember/dist;

    location / {
        index index.html;

    }  

    location ~* ^/json {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:80;
        proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
    }
}
```

Try to avoid use root inside the location block, it's a common pitfall as explained in [nginx documentation](http://wiki.nginx.org/Pitfalls#Root_inside_Location_Block)

Also you will need to configure another server to listen port 80.